# Metric with an uneven distribution of classes

Tags: classification, metric

I have a binary classification problem. There is 70 percent examples of first class and 30 percent of second one.

I have only features matrix and labels. There is no any additional information about data.

Which metrics are most suitable for evaluating the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 70-30 imbalance is small, and shouldn't be considered a problem for any of the popular metrics. The most commonly used metric is definitely [AUC](http://gim.unmc.edu/dxtests/roc3.htm). It evaluates the general quality of the ranking of instances by your classifier. If you want to fix the exact proportion of instances that should be classified positive, then precision@k is probably the best choice.

In general, I would recommend looking at diagnostic plots rather than single values. Two useful libraries in R are [ROCR](https://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/) and my [clasisiferplots](https://github.com/ambiata/classifierplots) library.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with unbalanced binary classification problems, looking at both the precision (ratio of true positives to true positives plus false positives) and the recall (ratio of true positives to true positives plus true negatives) is important. To do this for many threshold values, you can make a precision-recall curve.